# Why does my forloop run through my if statment only once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm writing a calculator in JS and currently I'm writing the '=' function, now I pasted my code below, so I made exp = 5 + 5, everything works fine it tells me that total is 10, now when I do 5+5+5 it still says 10, it's as if the loop ins't working, because I want it to do 5+5 first, update the total to be 10 and then find the + operator again and then add whatever is after the plus, how do I do this? I have no idea why the loop isn't working

All help is appreciated,

Have a nice day,
larwa

```
function equal(){

  var exp = document.form.textview.value;
  var expArray = exp.split(/\b/);
  console.log(expArray);
  let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0 ; i < expArray.length; i++){
      console.log(expArray[0])
      total = parseFloat(expArray[0])
      if(i = '+' || '-' || '/' || '*'){
      console.log(i);
      n = expArray.indexOf(i)
      total += parseFloat(expArray[n + 1]);
    }
   }
```

Comment: In the `if` statement you have `=` instead of `==` or `===`. You are assigning a new value to `i`.

Comment: `i = '+' || '-' || '/' || '*'`. You are doing assignment, instead it should comparison operator `==`. Also, separate expressions are required `i == '+' || i== '-' || i== '/' || i== '*'` or you can use includes. I guess you are doing comparison against the array elements and not against `i`.

Answer (score 2):

There are certain mistakes in your code.

The `total` should be initialized outside the `for` loop, otherwise it will generate incorrect total value.

`if(i = '+' || '-' || '/' || '*'){`, in this instead of using `assignment operator` i:e =, `comparison operator` i:e `==` or `===` (strict equality operator) should be used. As well separate comparison expressions are required i:e `i=== '+' || i=== '-' || i=== '/' || i=== '*'`. The `i` is nothing but index of the array elements, instead of `i` it should be array element. i:e `expArray[i]`.

```js
let exp = "5 + 5 + 5";

function equal() {
  var expArray = exp.split(/\b/);
  let total = parseFloat(expArray[0]);
  for (let i = 0; i < expArray.length; i++) {
    const dig = expArray[i].trim();
    if (dig === '+' || dig === '-' || dig === '/' || dig === '*') {
      total += parseFloat(expArray[i + 1]);
    }
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(equal());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    for (let i = 0 ; i < expArray.length; i++){
      console.log(expArray[0])
      total = parseFloat(expArray[0])
      if(i == '+' || '-' || '/' || '*'){
      console.log(i);
      n = expArray.indexOf(i)
      total += parseFloat(expArray[n + 1]);
    }
```

The `=` operator is used for assigning values to a variable, however the `==` operator is used for comparison between two variables irrespective of the datatype of variable

Comment: You should explain what was the issue with posted code and how does your solution solves the OP's problem?

Comment: `'+' || '-' || '/' || '*'` are truthy values.